# How to refresh asyncTask from another acctivity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am launching a activity, and once a user is logged in, i want to refresh the main activity. To load the data from the logged in user.

Such as the image and name. I have all of this set up already.

I just need to know is it possible to launch another activity and run its async task again.From an launching an intent from inside another activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly your design is, but if you need to use the same AsyncTask from two different activities, it should be a separate class, not tied to a particular activity. You can have the two activities implement a common interface, so that the AsyncTask doesn't need to know which activity it is updating. Then instantiate the task by passing a reference to the enclosing activity, and start it as needed. There is no need for one activity to start the other.

Something like:

```
public interface UserActivity {
  void updateUserData(UserData userData);
}

public class Activity1 implements UserActivity {

   public void onStart() {
      UpdateUserDataTask task = new UpdateUserDataTask(this);
      task.execute();
   }

   public void updateUserData(UserData userData) {
      // update
   }
}

public class UpdateUserDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, UserData> {
    UserActivity userActivity;

    public UpdateUserDataTask(UserActivitiy userActivity) {
       this.userActivity = userActivity;
    }

    // doInBackground, etc implementation.

    protected void onPostExecute(UserData userData) {
       userActivity.updateUserData(userData);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how do i launch the interface from another activity?

Comment: That is the point: don't launch it from another activity, launch it from each activity. If you have two activities, Activity1 and Activity2, when you back from 2 to 1, launch the task to refresh Activity1's data.

Comment: How do i launch the task from activity 2 when you go back to activity 1?

Comment: You launch it from Activity1's `onResume()` method, Activity2 doesn't need to know it at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, AsyncTasks aren't supposed to be reused. They're supposed to be run once and then you can create a new one if you need it.

Comment: Your right, But what i am trying to do is refresh the activity when some information is available in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Once an `AsyncTask` is executed once, you cannot execute it again. What you can do, though, is control it's "refresh" using `onProgressUpdate()` and `publishProgress()` as follows. Note that this will only work for a one-time refresh. If you wanted to be more semantically correct, you might do the "normal" operation in `onProgressUpdate()` and use `onPostExecute()` for your resfresh.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    private boolean isRefresh = false;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        while (!isRefresh){
            //Perform your normal operation
        }

    //When isRefresh is true, you want to refresh.  
        this.publishProgress(values);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // Refresh code here
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    public void refreshTask(){
        this.isRefresh = true;
    }

}
```

You could then maintain a reference to the object of `MyAsyncTask` and invoke `refreshTask()` on it whenever you want to refresh it.